# Multiple file upload tracking in Cherrypy 3.2

Tags: python, upload, statistics, progress, cherrypy

I have a simplistic CherryPy 3.2 web application, running on Windows 7, that successfully allows me to upload multiple files.  The application doesn't save or do anything special with the uploaded files at the moment, however.  I just want to do some testing first.  Anyways, the HTML snippet includes these lines

```
<form id="myform" action="doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />
<input type="submit" id="button" />
</form>
```

The corresponding CherryPy 3.2 dispatcher (with some lines of code removed) begins with

```
@cherrypy.expose
def doUpload(self, **kwargs):
    try:
        filesUploaded = 0
        for f in kwargs['files']:
            self.performActualUpload(f)
            filesUploaded = filesUploaded + 1

        if filesUploaded < 1: self.performActualUpload(kwargs['files'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

The self.performActualUpload() method has a very simple loop that just counts the number of bytes read and prints the total.  (I haven't used any logging features; I just dump all output to the Windows 7 command prompt).

```
size = 0
while True:
    try:
        data = f.file.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        size += len(data)
    except AttributeError:
        size = 0
print ("total bytes transferred is {}".format(size))
```

What I discovered is that the output from self.performActualUpload() is only generated *after* all files have been uploaded and *not during* the transfer.  What I want is to monitor the amount of bytes in transit so I can update an HTML field with either a growing progress bar or just an ever-changing numeric total.

I've trawled through Google searches and stumbled upon this thread http://old.nabble.com/File-upload-stats-in-CP-3.0-td13499294.html that talks about tracking file upload stats in CherryPy 3.0 but *not* with version 3.2 of the HTTP framework.

I understand that upload_stats() will have to be continuously called with something like a jQuery POST to ask CherryPy 3.2 for the latest upload statistics.  I also realise I need to create a FieldStorage object (the one with an overridden make_file() method).  What I cannot figure out, however, is how to successfully instantiate the FieldStorage object.  I tried the following lines of code in my doUpload() dispatcher

```
lcHDRS = {}
for key, val in cherrypy.request.headers.items():
    lcHDRS[key.lower()] = val

formFields = FieldStorage(fp=cherrypy.request.rfile,
                          headers=lcHDRS,
                          environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST'},
                          keep_blank_values=True)
```

only to receive this error message

```
ValueError: <cherrypy.wsgiserver.KnownLengthRFile object at 0x0000000003959198>
should return bytes, got str
```

KnownLengthRFile is a wrapper around a file-like object.  I tried to convert the str into bytes but that didn't work. So, I'm at a total loss on how to proceed from this point.  Admittedly, my knowledge of Python 3.2 and CherryPy 3.2 is quite limited at the moment.

Is there someone out there who can help me?  Again, I'm trying to adapt the code fragments over at http://old.nabble.com/File-upload-stats-in-CP-3.0-td13499294.html into a CherryPy 3.2 web application.  There's also some questions surrounding the whole AJAX interaction (i.e., calling upload_stats(), receiving a JSON entity and parsing it) but I'll reserve that for another time.  Thanks.

Comment: It turns about in CherryPy 3.2 doesn't use the standard library's CGI module anymore so the FieldStorage class isn't at play here.  Looks like I'll have to make use of _cpreqbody http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cpreqbody.html

Answer (score 2):

Use yield and return a streaming with the actual uploaded file size.

You can check yield with cherrypy here: http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ReturnVsYield

This is one of the cases where yield fits.